# I have text in a table field I want to wrap the text by using hover and if condition in Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, servlet-3.0

[image]

```
function dashboardTable(search){
    var date = $("#date_field").val();

    $.get(serverLocation + "Dashboard?date_field=" + date,function(responseText){
        var j=$.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(responseText));
        console.log(j);
        var html="<thead><tr><td style='width:30%;'onclick='sortColumn(\"agency_name\")'>Agency</td><td style='width:30%;' onclick='sortColumn(\"site_name\")'>Site</td><td onclick='sortColumn(\"slots\")'>Slots</td><td onclick='sortColumn(\"Enrollment\")'>Enrollment</td><td onclick='sortColumn(\"Percent\")'>Percent</td><td onclick='sortColumn(\"Waiting list\")'>WaitingList</td><td onclick='sortColumn(\"Pending list\")'>PendingList</td><td onclick='sortColumn(\"site_zip\")'>ZipCode</td></tr></thead>";

      for(var i=0;i<j.recordList.length;i++){

            html+="<tr><td>" + j.recordList[i]["agency_name"]+"</td><td>"+j.recordList[i]["site_name"]
              +"</td><td class = 'slot'>"+j.recordList[i]["slots"] +"</td><td class = 'enrollment'>"+ j.recordList[i]["Enrollment"] +"</td><td class = 'percent'>"+ j.recordList[i]["Percent"]+"</td><td class = 'waitinglist'>"
              + j.recordList[i]["Waiting list"]+"</td><td class = 'pendinglist'>"+ j.recordList[i]["Pending list"] +"</td><td>"+ j.recordList[i]["site_zip"]+"</td></tr>" ;

               }


    $("#child").html(html);


    });
    }
```

Comment: Hi all I am fresh graduate and I dont know java much please help me with this  is my html code and i attached picture to it i need to hover the table text that means i need to wrap the code to the next line withthe help of hover hits are if column is too long check length if over 10 create a div , set tittle attr to full text at column, insert first 10 characters in to div +++ or add div to td

Comment: please update your question with the information you just provided as a comment. I believe your question is about `javascript` and not `java,` as well. If you could please describe the end result you're looking to accomplish (for example: "when a user hovers over a cell, the cell turns red") rather than what you think is wrong with your current code, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on exactly what you want to script / automate.

CSS can switch your cursor to pointer providing the clickable indication to the user.

.myTd:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}

As for interacting with near elements on element hover, you can use a js `eventListener` for `mouseover` `mouseout` and use `event.target` to base your neighboring elements modifications, e.g. `event.target.nextElementSibling`, or maybe `event.target.innerHTML`, or maybe `event.target.classList.toggle("myClass").`